psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory on MAC M1 with Postgresql NOT installed with brew
I have exactly this problem but NONE of the solutions in this thread helped me:
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
I am suspecting that is caused by the fact that I installed Postgresql 16 with the Interactive Installer on the official website itself: https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ rather than using homebrew, hence now that I run into this problem, none of the homebrew commands on the above post can help me.
brew services restart postgresql commands will invariably return Error: Formula postgresql@14 is not installed.
Perhaps I need a non-homebrew solution? Can anyone suggest one for me though?
Thanks!

delete it and try it with homebrew

Have you read up on initialising Postgres? I don't remember it by heart, but something like pg_ctl init and pg_ctl start?

@Siguza pg_ctl cannot be found on my Mac M1, it is itself another question worthwhile asking on stackoverflow.

Instead of using brew, just download the app with the latest (5 different) version(-s): https://postgresapp.com

@FrankHeikens thanks, that seems a good solution in general. thanks a lot!
